# How to remove quotes in text using sed?

Tags: regex, linux, sed

How can I replace the following:
`password = "my_password"` to `password = my_password` using `sed` in linux?
and if there were no `""`  I should not do anything.

Comment: a simple `sed 's/"//g' file` will do this job..

Comment: To remove all ": `tr -d "\"" < file`

Comment: On just lines containing `password =` at the start, or on all lines?  Are spaces allowed before `password`?  Are spaces optional around the `=`?  Can there be trailing spaces or other garbage — will things be broken if the garbarge is left behind after the value of the password is removed from the quotes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say

```
sed 's/"\([^"]*\)"/\1/' filename
```

You're a little vague about your exact requirements; if you only want this substitution to take place in certain lines, use

```
sed '/pattern/ s/"\([^"]*\)"/\1/' filename
```

to restrict it to lines that match `pattern`. For example:

```
sed '/^password =/ s/"\([^"]*\)"/\1/' filename
```

to do it only in lines that begin with `password =`.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/password = \"\([^"]*\)\"/password = \1/'
```

Firstly, group the pattern within the double quotes => `\([^"]*\)` (i.e a sequence of non-double-quote characters). Now substitute `password = "patt_group"` with `password = patt_group` (`\1` => grouped pattern)